# I'm having trouble with my Jquery-Ajax upvoting code

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, django

In my project, it is possible to upvote posts. This works fine, when I'm not using Jquery-Ajax. It reloads the page, though, and I don't want that.

I implemented some Jquery-Ajax to do a POST request, and update the button to say ***upvoted***. Unfortunately, this causes all posts in the list to be upvoted, instead of just the one that I clicked.

Let me show you the HTML (inside the post list for loop):

```
{% for post in posts %}
{{ post.title }}
<hr>
{{ post.content }}
{% with user=request.user %}
    <a class="upvote" data-postid="{{ post.id }}"  href='#' >
        <span class="btn btn-primary" aria-hidden="true">
            Upvote | {{ post.followers }}
        </span>
    </a>

        {% endwith %}
        {% endfor {%
```

That was the HTML for the upvote and upvoted buttons.

Here is my Jquery script:

```
<script src="{% static 'posts/jquery-3.1.1.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".upvote").click(function(event){
var postid = $(this).data('postid');
$.ajax({url: "/activity/follow/10/{{ post.id }}?next={{ request.path }}&postid=" + postid, success: function (data) {
     event.preventDefault();

    $(".upvote").addClass('hidden');

    }


});

});
    </script>
```

To sum it up, how do I cause this function to **only vote on the post that I click**, instead of upvoting **every one in the list**? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the post ID for each upvote button? You need to get that in the `.click()` function, and send it as a parameter to the server.

Comment: @Barmar Ok. Could you please show me how that would be done?

Comment: Sorry, don't know django so I don't know how you would encode it into the `{%...%}` stuff.

Comment: Add `data-postid="{% post.id %}"` to the anchor, then you can do `var postid = $(this).data('postid');` in the `.click()` function, and add the post ID to the URL.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: @Barmar Is this better? `$(".upvote").click(function(event){
var postid = $(this).data('postid');
    $.ajax({url: "{% follow_url post %}?next={{ request.path }}", success: function (data) {
         event.preventDefault();

        $(".upvoted", this.parentElement).fadeIn();

        }


});

});`

Comment: You're not sending `postid` to the server. You need to add it as a URL parameter.

Comment: `"{% follow_url post %}?next={{ request.path }}&postid=" + postid`. Then change the server script so it updated the vote count for `$_GET['postid']`

Comment: @Barmar I did all of that, but it's still upvoting every post. Here's the updated script: `$(".upvote").click(function(event){
        var postid = $(this).data('postid');
    $.ajax({url: "{% follow_url post %}?next={{ request.path }}&postid=" + postid, success: function (data) {
         event.preventDefault();

        $(".upvoted", this.parentElement).fadeIn();

        }


});

});` I also updated the anchor to this : `<a class="upvote" data-postid="{{ post.id }}"    id="followpost">` What could I be missing here? Thanks again for all the help- it's much appreciated.

Comment: If you do View Source, do you see the correct post ID in the `data-postid` attributes? And does the server script use this parameter correctly?

Comment: Ok, finally fixed it by explicitly stating the post id in the URL. I guess that variable wasn't getting passed before. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: How will that work? You only have one piece of Javascript, it has to work with the IDs of all the vote buttons. That's why the ID should be in the HTML.

Comment: If you put the ID in the URL, you'll always upvote the same post.

Comment: @Barmar Yikes! I did something wrong in the testing, then. The `{{ post.id}}` is a variable, I didn't mean that I had the same id, like '3', in the URL. Anyway, it looks like it's running through the for loop of posts with that upvote code. Is there any way to ensure that it doesn't run through the loop? - I think that's the problem. It's getting the ID alright, but it won't stop with the single post that I like.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're doing wrong from that explanation. Add the new code to the end of your question. Also show the server code.

Comment: Okay- I updated the question's code. As I said, the `{{ post.id }}` represents the post's id, so it looks like that parameter has successfully been passed. However, it still upvotes every post in the loop.

Comment: What about the controller? Does it use the `postid` parameter to upvote the selected post? Also, `event.preventDefault()` should be in the `.click()` function, not the `success:` function.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry if I'm making some awful mistakes here, I'm  very new to JS. All the code is what I've shown you. Do I need a controller? If so, what do I put inside it?

Comment: The controller is the code that runs on the server that makes the database changes. It's `/activity/follow/10` on the server.

Comment: I see. In that case, the postid parameter would correspond to `{{ post.id }}` in the controller. I just need to upvote the post that is tied to the postid anchor, rather than all in the for-loop? What am I doing wrong in that regard? I think I changed the URL correctly, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `postid` variable into the controller URL, not `{{post.id}}`. The Javascript code shouldn't be in the loop, so it doesn't have access to the `post` variable.

```
$(".upvote").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var postid = $(this).data('postid');
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/activity/follow/10/" + postid + "?next={{ request.path }}", 
        success: function (data) {
            $this.addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank- this looks pretty good! Unfortunately, the URL isn't working. It's alright when I substitute `{{ post.id }}` for '+ postid +', but then it upvotes all the posts again. Otherwise, it doesn't do anything. Do you think the problem could be in the anchor? ---> `data-postid='{{ post.id }}'` I've done everything as you say, so I'm not sure what I'm still doing wrong.

Comment: Do you see the correct post ID in the HTML when you view the source? Other than that, I can't see what would be wrong.

Comment: @Bamar Yes, it's the correct post ID. It's written correctly in the URL, right-- it should be postid as opposed to data-postid?

Comment: Use the Network tab in the browser's console to see the AJAX request that's being sent. Does it have the correct post ID in it?

Comment: Odd, the ID is correct, but the console says 404: `jquery-3.1.1.js:9536 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/activity/follow/10/19?next=/posts/topic/2/ 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Do you think this is because it's GET rather than POST? The URL pattern is correct, and really ought to work.

Comment: Nevermind! I realized that I can remove the next parameter, b/c no redirects with Ajax. That solves it all! I can't thank you enough for all the help!